# show facebook audience network native ad for mobile web

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I've followed the guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/mobileweb/javascript/native-web to deploy the javascript tag and customize the native ad placement for my mobile web page.

I'm wondering if there is a way to generate the placements not at the time when page is loaded but later? for example, I want to popup an ad every 5 minutes and I don't want to load all of them in the beginning.

I've tried to append the following html code by javascript, but there is no response from the facebook and no ad fills in. Hope someone can help, thanks.

```
<fb:ad placementid="[PLACEMENT_ID]" format="native" nativeadid="ad_root"></fb:ad>
<div id="ad_root">
    <a class="fbAdLink">
        <div class="fbAdMedia thirdPartyMediaClass"></div>
        <div class="fbAdTitle thirdPartyTitleClass"></div>
        <div class="fbAdBody thirdPartyBodyClass"></div>
        <div class="fbAdCallToAction thirdPartyCallToActionClass"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to call `FB.XFBML.parse();` to trigger rendering again when the unit is added to the page via JS. The [fb docs for the function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) have more information.